# Creating Dependent Content Control Fields from Date Picker in MS Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm wanting to create some fields in a Word document where I select a date from a date picker content control at the top, and then that same date gets put in to the relevant spots elsewhere in the document. I've got dependent fields working from a combo box and rich text control set up before, but it doesn't seem to work tweaking for a date picker.

I did find this code which was intended to do what I wanted, I think:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim oCC As ContentControl
  Select Case ContentControl.Title
    Case "Date"
      Set oCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date Advanced").Item(1)
      With oCC
        .LockContents = False
        If IsDate(ContentControl.Range.Text) Then
          .Range.Text = DateAdd("d", 3, CDate(ContentControl.Range.Text))
        Else
          .Range.Text = vbNullString
        End If
      End With
  End Select
End Sub
```

But it didn't seem to do anything at all.

Ideally I wouldn't want to hard code the date format in, and just use the format that I can select in the content control properties window, though I am not sure if that's possible.

Comment: You should use mapped content controls for repeating data rather than using code. For dates there is already the built-in Publish Date control found under Insert | Quick Parts | Document Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

- `date1` and `date2` are `Plain Text Content Control`.

```vb
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim oCC As ContentControl, sDate As String
    With ContentControl
        If .Type = wdContentControlDate Then
            If .Title = "Date Advanced" Then
                .LockContents = False
                If IsDate(.Range.Text) Then
                    sDate = CStr(DateAdd("d", 3, CDate(.Range.Text)))
                    .Range.Text = sDate
                    For Each oCC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
                        If oCC.Type = wdContentControlText Then
                            oCC.Range.Text = sDate
                        End If
                    Next
                Else
                    .Range.Text = vbNullString
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Option 1 Update:

- Change date format with below code and the property of date content control

```vb
sDate = Format(DateAdd("d", 3, CDate(.Range.Text)), "dd MMMM yyyy")
```

[image]

---

Option 2: Use bookmarks

```vb
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim oBM As Bookmark, sDate As String
    With ContentControl
        If .Type = wdContentControlDate Then
            If .Title = "Date Advanced" Then
                .LockContents = False
                If IsDate(.Range.Text) Then
                    sDate = Format(DateAdd("d", 3, CDate(.Range.Text)), "dd MMMM yyyy")
                    .Range.Text = sDate
                    For Each oBM In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
                        If Left(oBM.Name, 4) = "date" Then
                            oBM.Range.Text = sDate
                        End If
                    Next
                Else
                    .Range.Text = vbNullString
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome thank you so much! The date formatting that I selected in the Date Picker isn't sticking, it's reverting from (dd MMMM yyyy) to (dd/mm/yyyy ). Can we tweak it so the formatting sticks?